# Value of the integer changes to some random number after scanf of other value I don't understand why

Tags: c

I am writing a program for my studies with dynamically allocated arrays and for some reason after scanf name in case(D) value of number of rooms is changed to random number. I really don't know why can anyone explain?

`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct Person
{
    char name;
    int number_of_keys;
}Person;

typedef struct Room
{
    int room_number;
    struct Person *key_holder; 
}Room;

void input_room(Room *_rooms, int _number_of_rooms)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < _number_of_rooms; i++)
    {
        scanf("%i", &((_rooms + i)->room_number));
        (_rooms + i)->key_holder = NULL;
    }
}

void output(Room *_rooms, int _number_of_rooms, Person *_people, int _num_of_people)
{
    printf("%i \n", _number_of_rooms);
    for(int i = 0; i < _number_of_rooms; i++)
    {
        printf("loop i=%i", i);
        printf("%i ", (_rooms + i)->room_number);
        printf("%s %i ", (_rooms + i)->key_holder->name, (_rooms + i)->key_holder->number_of_keys);
    }
}

void change_num_of_people(Person * _people, int _num_of_people)
{
    _people = realloc(_people, _num_of_people * sizeof(Person));
}

void fast(Room *_rooms, int _number_of_rooms)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < _number_of_rooms; i++)
        printf("%i \n", (_rooms + i)->room_number);
}

int main()
{
    int num_of_rooms, num_of_people = 0;
    char choice;
    int quit = 0;
    scanf("%i", &num_of_rooms);
    
    Room* rooms = malloc(num_of_rooms * sizeof(Room));
    input_room(rooms, num_of_rooms);
    //fast(rooms, num_of_rooms);
    //output(rooms, num_of_rooms);
    Person* people = malloc(num_of_people * sizeof(Person));
    
    while (quit == 0)
    {
        printf("%s \n", "new loop");
        getchar();
        choice = getchar();
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 'D':
            {
                
                char name;
                int room_index;
                printf("number of rooms = %i", num_of_rooms);        //value number of rooms changes
                scanf("%s", &name);                                     //after this scanf
                printf("number of rooms = %i", num_of_rooms);           
                scanf("%i", &room_index);
                
                num_of_people++;
                
                change_num_of_people(people, num_of_people);
                people[num_of_people - 1].name = name;
                people[num_of_people - 1].number_of_keys++;
                
                //printf("%s \n", "bef if");
                if(rooms[room_index].key_holder != NULL)
                {
                    //printf("%s \n", "in1 if");
                    rooms[room_index].key_holder->number_of_keys--;
                    //printf("%s \n", "in2 if");
                    if (rooms[room_index].key_holder->number_of_keys <= 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 1; i < num_of_people; i++)
                        {
                            people[i - 1] = people[i];
                        }

                        num_of_people--;
                        change_num_of_people(people, num_of_people);
                    }
                }
                rooms[room_index].key_holder = &(people[num_of_people - 1]);
                //printf("%s \n", "aft if");
                break;
            }
            case 'B':
            {
                break;
            }
            case 'P':
            {
                printf("%s \n", "bef if");
                printf("%i\n", num_of_rooms);
                output(rooms, num_of_rooms, people, num_of_people);
                printf("%s \n", "aft if");
                break;
            }
            case 'Q':
            {
                quit = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
        
    free(rooms);
    free(people);
    return 0;
}
```

`

I just found it by printing value of number_of_people and I don't know what to do about it

Comment: I would suggest compiling with warnings enabled. With `-Wall` you will have it much easier to spot errors which will help you a lot in the future.

Comment: At a glance: `scanf("%s", ...)` needs a multiple byte buffer to store a [null-terminated string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) in. `char name;` is a *single* byte. In each place it occurs, `char name` needs to be an array like `char name[64]`, or otherwise be a pointer to reasonably sized buffer. Then the assignment `people[num_of_people - 1].name = name;` needs to be replaced with `strcpy`, or simply scan the name directly into the structure (e.g., `scanf("%63s", people[num_of_people - 1].name)`).

Comment: Pointers are values. `_people = realloc(_people, _num_of_people * sizeof(Person));` only the local variable `_people` is changed to a new pointer value. In the caller's scope, `people` is not updated (but its pointer value is *invalidated* by the call to `realloc`, effectively creating a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer)). You need a pointer to it in order to update the value in the caller's scope. `Person **_people`, and `*_people = realloc(*_people, ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of issues ...

1. `name` in `Person` is a `char` but `output` prints with `%s` -- change to string
2. room's `key_holder` link *can* be `NULL` when printing in `output` -- must check for that. Otherwise, this causes a segfault [most likely cause of your issue].
3. `change_num_of_people` does *not* pass back the *updated* value of `_people` to `main` -- change to double pointer
4. Mixing `getchar` and `scanf` is bad juju.
5. Doing a lot of `scanf` calls without a `printf` to describe what to input is confusing.
6. Better to have pointers to the *current* room and person to eliminate a lot of (e.g. `rooms[room_index - 1].whatever`).
7. Compiling with `-Wall` would have flagged some of these issues.
8. Running under `gdb` would have spotted the segfault from `key_holder` being `NULL`

---

Here is the updated code. It is annotated with the bugs and fixes. I only checked the `D` and `P` commands, so probably more bugs. But, at least, it doesn't immediately crash.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#if 1
#include <string.h>
#endif

typedef struct Person {
// NOTE/BUG: this is printed as a string
#if 0
    char name;
#else
    char name[30];
#endif
    int number_of_keys;
} Person;

typedef struct Room {
    int room_number;
    struct Person *key_holder;
} Room;

void
input_room(Room *_rooms, int _number_of_rooms)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _number_of_rooms; i++) {
#if 1
        printf("Enter room number for %d\n",i);
#endif
        scanf("%i", &((_rooms + i)->room_number));
        (_rooms + i)->key_holder = NULL;
    }
}

void
output(Room *_rooms, int _number_of_rooms, Person *_people, int _num_of_people)
{
    printf("%i \n", _number_of_rooms);
    for (int i = 0; i < _number_of_rooms; i++) {
        Room *room = &_rooms[i];
        printf("loop i=%i", i);
        printf(" room=%i ", room->room_number);
// NOTE/BUG: room may not be assigned to a person, so link can be NULL
#if 0
        printf("%s %i ", (_rooms + i)->key_holder->name,
            (_rooms + i)->key_holder->number_of_keys);
#else
        struct Person *pers = room->key_holder;
        if (pers != NULL)
            printf("%s %i",pers->name,pers->number_of_keys);
        else
            printf("EMPTY");
        printf("\n");
#endif
    }
}

// NOTE/BUG: we must return the updated value
#if BUG
void
change_num_of_people(Person *_people, int _num_of_people)
{
    _people = realloc(_people, _num_of_people * sizeof(Person));
}
#else
void
change_num_of_people(Person **_people, int _num_of_people)
{
    *_people = realloc(*_people, _num_of_people * sizeof(Person));
}
#endif

void
fast(Room *_rooms, int _number_of_rooms)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _number_of_rooms; i++)
        printf("%i \n", (_rooms + i)->room_number);
}

int
main()
{
    int num_of_rooms, num_of_people = 0;
    char choice;
    int quit = 0;

#if 1
    printf("Enter number of rooms:\n");
    scanf("%i", &num_of_rooms);
#endif

    Room *rooms = malloc(num_of_rooms * sizeof(Room));

    input_room(rooms, num_of_rooms);
    // fast(rooms, num_of_rooms);
    // output(rooms, num_of_rooms);
    Person *people = malloc(num_of_people * sizeof(Person));

    while (quit == 0) {
        printf("new loop -- Enter D/B/P/Q\n");
// NOTE/BUG: don't intermix getchar and scanf
#if 0
        getchar();
        choice = getchar();
#else
        scanf(" %c",&choice);
#endif
        switch (choice) {
        case 'D':
            {

// NOTE/BUG: this should be a string
#if 0
                char name;
#else
                char name[30];
#endif
                int room_index;

                printf("number of rooms = %i\n", num_of_rooms);
#if 1
                printf("Enter holder name\n");
#endif
                scanf("%s", name);      // after this scanf
                printf("number of rooms = %i -- Enter room number",
                    num_of_rooms);
                scanf("%i", &room_index);

                num_of_people++;

// NOTE/BUG: we don't get the updated value of people
#if BUG
                change_num_of_people(people, num_of_people);
#else
                change_num_of_people(&people, num_of_people);
#endif

// NOTE/BUG: switch to string so we need strcpy
#if 0
                people[num_of_people - 1].name = name;
                people[num_of_people - 1].number_of_keys++;
#else
                Person *pers = &people[num_of_people - 1];
                strcpy(pers->name,name);
                pers->number_of_keys++;
#endif

                Room *room = &rooms[room_index];
                // printf("%s \n", "bef if");
                if (room->key_holder != NULL) {
                    // printf("%s \n", "in1 if");
                    room->key_holder->number_of_keys--;
                    // printf("%s \n", "in2 if");
                    if (room->key_holder->number_of_keys <= 0) {
                        for (int i = 1; i < num_of_people; i++) {
                            people[i - 1] = people[i];
                        }

                        num_of_people--;
                        change_num_of_people(&people, num_of_people);
                    }
                }
                room->key_holder = &(people[num_of_people - 1]);
                // printf("%s \n", "aft if");
                break;
            }
        case 'B':
            {
                break;
            }
        case 'P':
            {
                printf("%s \n", "bef if");
                printf("%i\n", num_of_rooms);
                output(rooms, num_of_rooms, people, num_of_people);
                printf("%s \n", "aft if");
                break;
            }
        case 'Q':
            {
                quit = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    free(rooms);
    free(people);
    return 0;
}
```

---

In the above code, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`